# Why Console of Chrome showing Map kind of Structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-console

Let say that my html is :

```
<div class="newEntry">
    <h1 class="entry"><img src=""></h1>
     <p>Josh : 2006</p>
</div>
```

Just for debugging purpose when i wrote

```
$("#newEntry").find("h1").find("img");
```

it is showing something like :

```
[prevObject: r.fn.init(0)]
```

while i want to see output as html items something like

```
 <h1 class="entry"><img src=""></h1>
```

Statements from Console

```
document.getElementsByClassName("newEntry");
[]
$("newEntry>h1")
[prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
$("#newEntry").find("h1").find("img");
[prevObject: r.fn.init(0)]
$("#newEntry").find("h1");
[prevObject: r.fn.init]length: 0prevObject: r.fn.init {}__proto__: Object(0)
$("#newEntry").find("h1").find("img");
[prevObject: r.fn.init(0)]
$("#newEntry").find("h1").find("img").html();
undefined
$("#newEntry").find("h1").html();
undefined
$("#newEntry").html();
undefined
```

Comment: What exactly are you logging? Please include your `console.log` statement.

Comment: `$(".newEntry").find("h1").find("img").parent()[0].outerHTML`

Comment: If you want to show the HTML of whatever you're looking for, you need to ask for the HTML. By default, the [jQuery find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) function returns an object.

Answer (score 2):

You have used `#newEntry` which is used to get the elements by ID in jquery. But in your `<div>` you haven't defined a ID. So, you need to use a class selector.

You need to use the `.html()` [to get the exact content](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

```
$(".newEntry").find("h1").html();
```

Comment: No its not working $("#newEntry").html() itself is showing undefined !!!!!

Comment: Use .newEntry, # is used for ID's

Answer (score 0):

`[prevObject: r.fn.init(0)]` that the element your are looking for was not found. Because your are using '#' symbol for a class.
You should do :

```
<div class="newEntry">
    <h1 class="entry"><img src=""></h1>
     <p>Josh : 2006</p>
</div>
```

and

```
$(".newEntry:first").find("h1").find("img");
```

**or**

```
<div id="newEntry">
    <h1 class="entry"><img src=""></h1>
     <p>Josh : 2006</p>
</div>
```

and

```
$("#newEntry").find("h1").find("img");
```

Comment: $(".newEntry") is again showing map kind of structure !!!
do i need to make any setting changes in chrome console !!
[prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]

Comment: Look at this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/msrx037L/)
I used the attr to show that i can get the image.
And no you should not need to change any settiings from your chrome comsole to have the good result

Comment: `[prevObject: r.fn.init(1)] `, notice `(1)`, it found the object right? Try what Jaromanda suggested in the question comments? `$(".newEntry").find("h1").find("img").parent()[0].outerHTML`

Comment: What is the point of getting an element then its parent to finally get the first child ? Cann't you simply do : `$(".newEntry").find("h1")[0].outerHTML` ?

Comment: `<h1>some title</h1><h1><span>title with image</span><img src="img.jpg" /></h1>` The difference being that your code returns both the `<h1>` tags, the one originally suggested by Jaromanda returns only the one with an image. Though the `find()` could be simplified to: `.find('h1 > img')`

Comment: That's what i meant. This idea was not wrong but too complicated. You can do even simpler, just set an id on your img and get it through the id.